# ExtNet GridPanel Grouping Column-Data Dynamic

Tags: asp.net, extjs, grouping, ext.net, gridpanel

I ll develop new web project and i want to use extnet. But in my web project, users must grouping GridPanel columns dynamic like devexpress GridViews.

https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GroupingSorting/Grouping.aspx

http://forums.ext.net/attachment.php?attachmentid=17892&d=1419930599

Can i do  that with ExtNet?

Comment: why don't you use devexpress ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://examples.ext.net/#/DataView/Advanced/Grouping/

Comment: Devexpress is cool and use devexpress in my web projects. But this project ll be very big. Devexpress is heavy. So i cant use. @MairajAhmad

Comment: Have you checked the link i have given ?

Comment: This example not for me. Grouping must be dynamic. User could grouping data dynamic. Drag and drop grid columns for grouping. @MairajAhmad